# Method sortable does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [Kyslik sortable package](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable) in my APP. Sortable works fine when retrieving data from single table without doing any relations.

Below code throw an error: **Method sortable does not exist.**
So what can i do ? How to retrieve subtopics that belong to single topic but also call sortable for sorting data in view ?

```
public function showSubtopics($id)
    {
        $subtopics = Topic::find($id)->subtopics-> sortable()->paginate(5);
        return view('subtopic.index', compact('subtopics'));
    }
```

Comment: Is the `Sortable` trait correctly applied to your `subtopics` model?

Comment: Has it something to do with the space between `->` and `sortable`?

Comment: have you added `use Sortable;` to your model? Both topic and subtopic if it's a relation

Comment: You may also want to do `->subtopics()` instead of `->subtopics`, but I'm not 100% certain of that.

Comment: Yes, i have added 

use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;

 use Sortable;
 public $sortable = ['name'];

in model.

Also in view i added @sortablelink('name')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one this

```
  public function showSubtopics($id)
{
    $subtopics = Topic::find($id)->subtopics()->sortable()->paginate(5);
    return view('subtopic.index', compact('subtopics'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing ->subtopics to ->subtopics() solved the issue. Thanks to @ceejaoz